# Why are my useRef input values not being passed to my GraphQL mutation?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mutation

I'm using `useRef` on two inputs so that I can have them in a modal without the state rerendering and the inputs losing focus after each key press. The issue Im running into now is that when I try to call my mutation, I get an error saying my variables are empty, even though Im passing the `useRef`'s values to them. Any ideas why the `useRef` variables are not being passed to the mutation?

```
const firstNameRef = useRef();
const lastNameRef = useRef();

const createClientsModal = () => {
  return (
    <Modal
      modalHeader={<h2>Create New Terminal</h2>}
      hideButtons={false}
      buttonContent={"Save"}
      closeModal={setShow}
      click={createClient}
    >
      <>
        <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
        <Input
          style={{ marginTop: "10px", marginBottom: "25px" }}
          type="text"
          ref={firstNameRef}
        />
        <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
        <Input style={{ marginTop: "10px" }} type="text" ref={lastNameRef} />
      </>
    </Modal>
  );
};

const [testCreate] = useMutation(CREATE_CLIENT, {
  errorPolicy: "all",
  variables: {
    data: {
      clinic: {
        connect: {
          id: id,
        },
      },
      firstName: firstNameRef.current?.value,
      lastName: lastNameRef.current?.value,
    },
  },
});

const createClient = () => {
  console.log(firstNameRef.current?.value, lastNameRef.current?.value); // <<<< This log does successfully log the ref values
  testCreate().then(() => {
    refetch();
    setShow(false);
  });
};
```

Comment: *I'm using useRef on two inputs so that I can have them in a modal without the state rerendering and the inputs losing focus after each key press.* Not an answer to your question, but this is definately not a thing. You are most likely doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever React renders or re-renders, your `useMutation` hook is invoked with the current values.

So when you update the ref-values in the `onChange`, the `useMutation` hook is **not** called again (because there is no re-render) and still has the initial values.

To solve this, one option could be to pass the variables when you call `testCreate` instead of passing them to `useMutation`. So something like this:

```
const [testCreate] = useMutation(CREATE_CLIENT, {
  errorPolicy: "all",
});

const createClient = () => {
  testCreate({
    variables:
      data: {
        ...
        firstName: firstNameRef.current?.value,
        lastName: lastNameRef.current?.value,
      },
    },
  }).then(() => {
    refetch();
    setShow(false);
  });
};
```

My suggestion, however, would be to try using `useState` again and figure out how to avoid the issue with the loss of focus. For your use case, `useState` is the recommended hook to use. Maybe [this documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/input#controlling-an-input-with-a-state-variable) could be helpful to you.